# Is it okay to have a model to contain a column of the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Language` model and it makes semantic sense to name a column in it "language".

Is this possible and aside from sounding a bit strange (e.g. `Language.language`), can it be risky (e.g. namespace collisions etc)?

Comment: It is possible, maybe a bit confusing in code maintenance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible**: definitely.

**Namespace collisions**: Likely no.

**Sounding a bit strange**: Yes, it does.

How about calling it `language_name` or just **`name`**? That way you can access it like `Language.name` and query as `Language.find_by_name` and so on.